# How to get both the greedy and optimal solution in A* search

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence

I am studying A* search in artificial intelligence. 
In this Romania map with straight distance line as h(n), I am searching a path from Arad to Bucharest using A* search.

[image]

After RV(220+193=413, A -> S-> RV) is expanded, Fagaras is expanded instead of Pittesti.

Why is Fagaras is expanded instead of directly expanding Pittesti?

Comment: Your title doesn't match the body of your post. Do you want to understand why A* works the way it does or do you want to know how to get both the greedy and optimal solution in A* (although you'll have to define what greedy means in the latter context)?

Comment: Get the distance so far for each node, add "expected" distance, explore the node with lowest sum. That's all there is to A*. Calculate that for every node you visit, double check everything, if something doesn't add up, or just to be safe, triple check everything, if you're still confused, only then ask a question. You seem to be missing the part where you calculated that for every node, requiring us to duplicate work you should've already done instead of just pointing out your mistake - that's mostly just wasting our time.